# Filehelpers Field max length

Tags: validation, field, maxlength, filehelpers

I'm working with Filehelpers and imported a csv File. Everything works fine, but now I want to validate the length of the imported Fields.

```
[DelimitedRecord(";")]
public class ImportFile
{
    public string Name;
    public string NameSurname;
}
```

Is there a possible way, that I can create an attribute "MaxLength" which split the Input String or Throw an Exception, if the InputString is bigger than my MaxLength Attribut?
The only thing I found was the FieldFlixedLength, but thats only the Split, the Inputfile in fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement an `AfterRead` event as follows:

```
[DelimitedRecord(";")]
public class ImportRecord : INotifyRead<ImportRecord>
{
    public string Name;         
    public string NameSurname;

    public void BeforeRead(BeforeReadEventArgs<ImportRecord> e)
    {
    }

    public void AfterRead(AfterReadEventArgs<ImportRecord> e)
    {
        if (e.Record.Name.Length > 20)
            throw new Exception("Line " + e.LineNumber + ": First name is too long");

        if (e.Record.NameSurname.Length > 20)
            throw new Exception("Line " + e.LineNumber + ": Surname name is too long");
    }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<ImportRecord>();
        engine.ErrorMode = ErrorMode.SaveAndContinue;

        string fileAsString = "Firstname;SurnameIsAVeryLongName" + Environment.NewLine
                            + "FirstName;SurnameIsShort";

        ImportRecord[] validRecords = engine.ReadString(fileAsString);

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        foreach (ErrorInfo error in engine.ErrorManager.Errors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.ExceptionInfo.Message);
        }

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;            
        foreach (ImportRecord validRecord in validRecords)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Successfully read record: {0} {1}", validRecord.Name, validRecord.NameSurname));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```